# Submitting a job on PBS with while loop, changing output file names

Tags: loops, pbs, qsub

I have a (let's call it original) script to parse a file (~1000 lines) line by line, generate arguments to execute a C++ program.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    i = 0
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        a="$line" | cut -c1-2
        b="$line" | cut -c3-4
        c="$line" | cut -c5-6
        d="$line" | cut -c7-8
        e="$line" | cut -c9-10
        f="$line" | cut -c11-12
        g="$line" | cut -c13-14
        h="$line" | cut -c15-16
        i="$line" | cut -c17-18
        j="$line" | cut -c19-20
        k="$line" | cut -c21-22
        l="$line" | cut -c23-24
        m="$line" | cut -c25-26
        n="$line" | cut -c27-28
        o="$line" | cut -c29-30
        p="$line" | cut -c31-32
        ./a.out "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d" "$e" "$f" "$g" "$h" "$i" "$j" "$k" "$l" "$m" "$n" "$o" "$p" > $(echo some-folder/output_${i}.txt)
    done < test_10.txt
```

I want to schedule this job in a batch, so that each run is queued and ran on separate cores.

I checked the PBS and qsub writing styles. I could write a PBS file (simple one, without all options for now. Lets call it callPBS.PBS):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
qsub ./a.out -F "my arguments"
exit 0
```

I can call this file instead of ./a.out -------- in original script. BUT how do I pass "my arguments"? Problem is they are not fixed.

Secondly I know qsub takes -o as an option for output file. But I want my output file name to be changed. I can pass that as an argument again, but how?

Can I do this in my original script:

```
callPBS.pbs > $(echo some-folder/output_${i}.txt)
```

I am sorry if I am missing something here. I am trying to use all that I know!

Comment: You included the C++ tag, but I don't see any C++ code or content relating to C++.  Did I miss something?  You issue has more to do with executables; executables can be written from any language.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I am sorry for the confusing tag. My program to be scheduled is in C++. And it runs fine. I would rather remove that tag.

Comment: What you are doing looks like it'd work. Have you tried it?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Actually, I have tried changing my way a bit, as I found what I proposed in the solution above is inefficient as in it needs creating 1000 files. I will upload my new thing soon, but it is not working as of now.